# JCheckbox in jtable storing values in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

Hi I've this problem : I want to store the checkbox values in a mysql database and loading values for it from that database with this code:

```
String [][]Database = new String[500][10];
     String query=null;
     PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
     ResultSet res=null;  
     int i=0;
       query= "SELECT * FROM dipendenti  ";
       try {
           pstmt=Connessioni.connection.con.prepareStatement(query);
           res=pstmt.executeQuery();

           while(res.next()){
               Database[i][0]=res.getString("nome");
               Database[i][1]=res.getString("codice");
               Database[i][2]=res.getString("livello");
               Database[i][3]=res.getString("cc");
               Database[i][4]=res.getString("ca");
               Database[i][5]=res.getString("successo");
               System.out.println("OK");
               i++;
           }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

    String [] tool = {"Nome","Codice","Livello","Data_CC","Data_CA","SUCCESSO"};

    DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel(null,tool){
     @Override
     public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {      
        return false;       
     }

     public Class getColumnClass(int col) {  
        if (col == 5) {  
           return Boolean.class;  
        }  
        return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();  
     } 
};

while(i>0){

  m.addRow(Database[i-1]); //-1 perchè i parte da n e non da n-1
  i--;
}
brooker = new JTable(m);
```

But when i've something to load in the program from database, the program lags and it becomes all black and I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at agenda_brooker.PaginaPrincipale$1.getColumnClass(PaginaPrincipale.java:95)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getColumnClass(JTable.java:2701)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getCellRenderer(JTable.java:5686)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2113)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1482)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1413)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: It looks like one of the values are pulling from the database is null. Since you are using rs.getString(), all the column values are going to be String any way. Using getColumnClass in this way really isn't recommended

Comment: Use proper Java variable names. Variable names do not start with an upper case letter.

Comment: your getColumnClass is correct, have to create an Boolean value from Resultset

Comment: You're passing null as the first argument to your table model, instead of passing the data. Also, are you sure you have exactly 500 rows in your table? If not why not use a List instead of an array. And finally, why are you returning Boolean.class in getColumnClass() since the data is in fact a String? Oh, and why does your array have 10 columns since you only use 6?